# Can't get my JavaScript pause button to resume - so close to being done

Tags: javascript, jquery

After many different codes, this is the closest I have been to it all working. Every button works (prev, next, & pause), but I need to set the pause button to resume the slideshow after it is clicked a second time. I don't care if the slideshow resumes where it left off, just as long as it resumes. I also do not want to add a 4th (play) button or for the pause button to change to a play button, just simply toggle (stop the show/restart the show).

This is so close to working. Who can help me add the proper thing to this to make it work (resume) without writing a whole new code? Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.fadein img:gt()').hide();
    var active = true;
    var interval = setInterval(intervalFunction, 4000);

    $('.pauseButton').click(function () {
        if (!active) interval = setInterval(intervalFunction, 4000);
        else clearInterval(interval);
    });

    function intervalFunction() {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.nextButton').on('click', function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    });
    $('.previousButton').on('click', function () {
        $('.fadein :last-child').fadeIn()
            .insertBefore($('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut());
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.fadein { position:relative; width:450px; height:275px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }

#showcontainer {
    width: 530px;
    height: 315px; }
#btn1 {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px; }
#show {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    height: 275px; }
#btn2 {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px; }
#btn3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px; }

.nextButton, .previousButton, .pauseButton { cursor: pointer }

.content {
    color: #443e33;
    line-height: 150%;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="showcontainer">
  <div id="btn1"><img src="../images/btn_prev.png" width="40" height="80" vspace="100" class="previousButton"/></div>
    <div id="show" class="fadein">
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide1.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide2.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide3.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide4.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide5.png" width="450" height="275" />
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide6.png" width="450" height="275" /> 
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide7.png" width="450" height="275" /> 
         <img src="../gallery/slide/slide8.png" width="450" height="275" />           
    </div>    
  <div id="btn2"><img src="../images/btn_next.png" width="40" height="80" vspace="100" class="nextButton"/></div><br />
  <div id="btn3"><img src="../images/btn_pause.png" width="80" height="30" class="pauseButton"/></div>  
</div>      


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8mNAn/1/
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Not really that hard: http://dummyimage.com/

Comment: small preference for this one: http://placekitten.com/

Comment: Updated fiddle with images, and jQuery actually selected: http://jsfiddle.net/jzL5E/

Comment: I do not see where you are setting active to false.

Comment: @Jamiec, thanks for the dummyimage link. I didn't know that existed. I was working on it, but you are much quicker than I am. Thanks again! I'll save that for next time.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you've forgotten to toggle the `active` flag:

```
$('.pauseButton').click(function () {
    if (!active) interval = setInterval(intervalFunction, 4000);
    else clearInterval(interval);

    active = !active; // << MISSING BIT
});
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks rixo! I had that in there yesterday, but apparently I was missing a semi-colon somewhere. So between your answer & the fact that I learned about jsfiddle and how it will clean up the code, I finally have success! All you guys are great! Thanks again!